# Is the None stride in Keras MaxPooling2D dynamically set according to filter size?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am building a CNN on 112 x 92 images using Keras. After each conv layer I insert a MaxPooling2D layer. I am a little confused on how the output matrix dimensions are being calculated. I am using a (2,2) filter in each MaxPooling2D layer with strides set as 1) None 2) (1,1) and 3) (2,2). The output matrix of 1) and 3) are same (which as per my understanding shouldn't be, as None should be (1,1)). For further experimentation, I changed the filter size to (3,3), keeping the strides as None, and now the matrix dimensions are reduced by a factor of 3. Why is this the case? Is the None stride dynamically set?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as per the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/pooling_layers/max_pooling2d/):

> Integer, tuple of 2 integers, or None. Strides values. Specifies how far the pooling window moves for each pooling step. If None, it will default to pool_size.